# If $\gamma(t) = t + it^2$ and $f(z) = xy^2-iyx^2$ how do we compute $f(\gamma(t))$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\gamma(t) = t + it^2$ and $f(z) = xy^2-iyx^2$ how do we compute $f(\gamma(t))$? I'm confused because there are no values of $z$ stated explicitly for $f(z).$ I can do this easily with functions like $f(v) = 1/v,$ but am having trouble in this case. It's confusing trying to plug in $\gamma(t)$ of one variable into two variable component functions $u(x,y)$ and $iv(x,y).$ Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are confused because there are tacit assumptions made in your source, namely (a) that $t$ is a real variable, and (b) that $x={\rm Re}(z)$, $y={\rm Im}(z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, think of it as $f(x+iy)$. Can you see how to calculate $f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)=f\left(t+it^2\right)$ from that?

More cumbersomely, you can always remember that if $z=x+iy,$ then $$x=\frac{z+\overline z}2,y=\frac{z-\overline z}{2i},$$ which you can use to find $f(z)$ explicitly in terms of $z$.

Comment: $x = t$ and $y = t^2$?

Comment: Yep! That's the idea.

Comment: Thank you, very useful answer